# Disable QSizeGrip for QMainWindow

Tags: windows, qt, qt5

I have been trying to disable the resize grip after setting the fixed width of the main window. I read in the Qt forms that setting the `statusBar()->setSizeGripEnabled()` as `false` would disable the resize grip, but no luck. I am running this on `Qt5`.

I know that removing the frame would remove this problem but that's a bigger problem (creating ways to drag the window, adding buttons to close etc.). So far this is what I have in my `main` method:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
   QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
QApplication a(argc, argv);
Compressor w;
w.statusBar()->setSizeGripEnabled( false );
w.setFixedSize(QSize(360,450));
w.setGeometry(
            QStyle::alignedRect(
                Qt::LeftToRight,
                Qt::AlignCenter,
                w.size(),
                a.desktop()->availableGeometry()
                )
            );
w.show();
```

The `setGeometry` sets the window on the centre of the screen on startup, Fixed it to a size. I am not sure what the problem is. Is there any way to fix this?

**Update**

Setting the `w.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Fixed);` Didn't work. Tried fixing both to `Fixed`, no luck.

**Update 2**

I even remove the status bar, but still no luck.

**Update 3**

Example:

[image]

On Windows 10 using version Qt 5.10.1

Comment: @eyllanesc so that the main window cannot be resized

Comment: @eyllanesc you mean by removing QSize and just put in the number?

Comment: @eyllanesc The problem is that I still get that resize arrows at the edge of the window, all sides actually.

Comment: You can show an image, at least I do not observe them, I'm using it in Linux with Qt 5.10.1

Comment: @eyllanesc example added

Comment: You must indicate which is your OS and the version of Qt, it seems a bug

Comment: @eyllanesc I have updated it, ya I guess so.

Comment: I recommend reporting it: https://bugreports.qt.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows seems to be a bit adamant about being the cross-platform friendly OS. The way to fix the problem is by adding a window flag. The code:

goes into your `main.cpp`:

```
// Disable resize arrow.
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
#endif
```

Complete code:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
   QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
QApplication a(argc, argv);
Compressor w;

// Disable resize arrow.
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
#endif

w.setFixedSize(QSize(360,450));
w.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
w.setGeometry(
            QStyle::alignedRect(
                Qt::LeftToRight,
                Qt::AlignCenter,
                w.size(),
                a.desktop()->availableGeometry()
                )
            );
w.show();
```

**OR**

You can also add it to your `MainWindow.cpp` file as:

```
this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
```

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum for more.